# Number conversion in PHP

Tags: php

I'm creating a site where users have to input several numbers.
Theese numbers have to be validated (for illegal characters etc.) and converted to the format:

```
1234.56
```

My problem is how do I convert (due to the different country notations) the different combinations of decimal/thousand-delimiters:

```
1234,56 / 1.234,56 / 1234.56 / 1,234.56
```

The expected result should always be : `1234.56`

Comment: Define *how* the user should input the numbers, at least what the decimal separator is.

Comment: Can you assume that there will always be two decimals? .. or that there always will be decimals?

Comment: unfortunately I can't assume anything.
It's an input-field with no client-side validation, so the user could (by mistake) key in alpha-chars, in wich case my validaion-function should return an error.
So I have to do all the validation server-side

Answer (score 1):

If you always have 2 decimal places (as for prices or so), you could just take the last dot or comma, split the input string at this position and remove all non-numeric characters (, and . in your case) from the first part.

If you can't guarantee to have two decimal places, you need to get tricky by checking, if there are 3 numbers after the last separator (to decide if there are decimal places).

Since apparently you need to support a larger set of countries, a generic solution might be the best choice. Maybe there is some Javascript, which solves the problem as well (converts numbers before submitting a form).

Answer (score 0):

You can use zend framework component: Zend_Locale_Format::getNumber() function. http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.locale.parsing.html